# SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition or Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server

We are looking to upgrade our database server to SQL Server 2008 R2 . There is a big price difference between the web edition and the standard edition. Which features does the standard edition have, that the web edition doesn't have.

For example, we would like to have a scheduled backup for our databases. Is this possible in both editions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

it provides a matrix of what is supported in each version.  Standard has many more advanced features than Web such as the edit and design tools as well as not being able to duplicate data between more than one database, though there are some free options you can use to make up for what Web lacks.